# How to use `SecureRoute` with React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, wso2-asgardeo

I'm using Asgradeo react ADK along with React Router v6. With React Router v5 the `SecureRoute` works fine. But, for v6 it doesn't. Is there any different API implemented for React Router v6?
Didn't find in API documentation https://github.com/asgardeo/asgardeo-auth-react-sdk/blob/main/API.md#securing-routes-with-asgardeo

```html
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage/>}/>
                <SecureRoute path="/home" callback={()=>signIn()} component={HomePage}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Give following error.

```
[Wi] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
    at invariant (http://localhost:3000/main.js:1993:11)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.js:40020:108
    at http://localhost:3000/main.js:42639:17
    at http://localhost:3000/main.js:42602:17
    at mapIntoArray (http://localhost:3000/main.js:42493:23)
    at mapIntoArray (http://localhost:3000/main.js:42543:23)
    at mapChildren (http://localhost:3000/main.js:42601:3)
    at Object.forEachChildren [as forEach] (http://localhost:3000/main.js:42638:3)
    at createRoutesFromChildren (http://localhost:3000/main.js:40005:47)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/main.js:39848:20)
```

I'm using `@asgardeo/auth-react` - v2.0.3 along with `react-router-dom` - v6.3.0